# Tensorflow deep learning question

Tags: neural-networks

[image]

In the example above, there are two loops. Why is running the second loop valid? We already trained the network 1000 from the first loop, does running the second loop mean we trained it 2000 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop is measuring the accuracy of the trained model on the hold-out data.

We know that the model parameters are not updated in the second loop because the `train` node is not accessed by the `sess.run` method.

Comment: I don't understand, both loops use sess.run().

Comment: Yeah, but `sess.run` is how you obtain **any** output from a TF network. Importantly, `sess.run` it's *not* the same as training, as stated in the second sentence of the answer. The difference is which node of the computation graph you're accessing. The TF documentation is a great place to start understanding TF.